# How can I get the arguments of the function Graph?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

If I have

```
f0 = f[x,y,z]
```

and I am interested in the list of the arguments, what I do is

```
In[1]:= args = Apply[ List, f0 ]
Out[1]= {x, y, z}
```

Apparently this doesn't work with the function "Graph"

```
In[2]:= gr = CycleGraph[3];

In[3]:= gr // InputForm

Out[3]//InputForm= 
  Graph[{1, 2, 3}, 
  {UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[3, 1]}, 
  {VertexCoordinates -> {{0.8660254037844388, -0.4999999999999998},
  {-0.8660254037844384, -0.5000000000000004}, {-2.4492935982947064*^-16, 1.}}}]
```

When I try

```
args = Apply[ List, gr ]
```

what happens is that the graph is drawn and that's it. The following doesn't work either

```
args = Apply[ List, InputForm[gr] ]
```

Any explanation or workaround?

Comment: Since `Graph[]` is an atomic object (see [this related thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26335)), you cannot use things like `Apply[]` or `Part[]` on it. Instead, use `VertexList[]` and `EdgeList[]` to extract vertices and edges, respectively. Additionally, look up `PropertyValue[]`. Someone else might want to write an elaboration of this comment.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Graph` is an [atomic expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AtomQ.html).  It is not a Mathematica expression made up of a head and multiple "arguments", even though sometimes it vaguely looks like one.  Instead you should treat it as *an indivisible unit*.

Use `VertexList`, `EdgeList`, `PropertyValue`, etc. to extract information from it.

---

We should distinguish between a truly atomic `Graph` object, and a compound expression with head `Graph`.  When you type `Graph[{1,2,3},{1<->2}]` in Mathematica, you are indeed writing a compound expression which can be manipulated like any other.  For example:

```
g = Hold@Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 <-> 2}]
(* Hold[Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 <-> 2}]] *)

g[[1, 1]]
(* {1, 2, 3} *)
```

However, this compound expression immediately evaluates to an atomic `Graph`:

```
AtomQ@ReleaseHold[g]
(* True *)
```

After that it is no longer possible to access its parts (because it has no parts).

As you can see, not every expression with [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) `Graph` is an atomic `Graph` object.  To test if one is, use the [`GraphQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphQ.html) function. For example:

```
GraphQ@Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {2 <-> 3}]
(* True *)

GraphQ@Graph[asd]
(* False *)
```

`Graph[asd]` is not a valid way to construct a graph, so instead of evaluating to a true graph, it stays as a compound expression.

---

To make this answer complete, I should note that atomic `Graph` objects do in fact have a representation as a compound expression, but these are not meant to be used by end users.  They are used internally for serialization, such as storing a graph in a notebook, sending it through MathLink, `Compress`ing it, etc. See my two answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96225/12) on how to get to it.

Since these representations are not meant for end users, they are undocumented (meaning that you might easily encounter unexpected forms – don't assume that inspecting one graph tells you how others are represented) and may be different between different Mathematica versions.

Comment: It's more or less clear now. It felt kind of funny that I could print, using InputForm, the argument list on the display of my PC and assign it to a variable using a mouse with cut and paste, but I could not do it programmatically... :-)

Comment: @brian0 Well, you *can* do it programmatically with the tricks I linked to, but it's really not a good idea (other than looking at it for curiosity).  I looked at Graph and as I remember I found at least three different representations.  If you're interested in poking around in the internals, also check out ``GraphComputation`GraphRepresentation`` and ``GraphComputation`ToGraphRepresentation``.  I looked at these because I was desperate to find a faster way to transfer graphs to LibraryLink in some form for [IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM)). But eventually I gave up on it ...